# Handling/editing special characters in a huge file(>2gb)

Tags: csv, double-quotes

I used java to write into and create a csv file. Since certain fields had ',' in them as part of values I enclosed each column with ' "" ' ((like "allen,jade","123","12 street" )). So the values in my csv file looks like:

"col a value", "col b value" ....

Now when I was trying to upload this file into a postgres (9.1) database using
 COPY tablea  from 'filename.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
 I got an error saying:  extra data after last expected column.

I inspected the record for which the error was displayed and it has a column which has ' " ' as a part of its value.

Precisely this is how it is:

"Halswell Congregation of Jehovah"s Witnesses Christchurch","Christchurch","Halswell Congregation of Jehovah"s Witnesses"

I am guessing it's because of the ' " ' inside the value in the first column that I'm getting this error.

Please correct me if I'm wrong and it would be awesome if you could help me get around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating your CSV file, you should be escaping any existent quotes (replace `"` with `\"`) before wrapping them in your own quotes.

Comment: I understand but is there any way to work with the existing csv file without having to generate it again because it's a huge file, takes ages to generate.

Comment: If it takes ages to generate, it probably also takes ages to process. Also, there is no unambiguous way to recognise a quote you inserted from a quote that existed before. For example, say you had a Biography field that contained `I like "War and Peace", "Ana Karenina" and other Tolstoy works` - the quotes around the comma would be indistinguishable from your inserted quotes.

Comment: I'm thinking of reading the file one line at a time. Then splitting the lines into parts considering ',' as delimiter and then change all the occurrences of '"' to '\"' which are not the first and the last character of the split item. It should work aye?

Comment: I just gave you an example where it wouldn't. Actually, not quite - but say you have another Tolstoy's book in there - breaks your algorithm. Basically, whatever algorithm you take, there will be some input that will break it. It might be improbable, so if you think you know your data you might go for it.

Comment: Oh perfect. What do I do now? Should I just hope that there doesn't exist any record as such.

Comment: You could try doing that - escape any quotes that are not next to edge of string or a comma - then see if it worked. Maybe your data is such that no ambiguity exists, in which case you'd be lucky. Then if it doesn't, it's generating time. Good luck